# How to get graph network statistics in python's graphviz library?

Tags: python, graphviz

I have a .gv file and I need to get statistics in python like:

- Number of Edges
- Number of Nodes
- Number of trees in network
- nodes and edges per tree

How can I get this information in python?

Comment: You mean a .gv file?

Comment: yes. thank you! Updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pygraphviz](https://pygraphviz.github.io/), for example.

```
$ pip3 install pygraphviz
```

Then in python, to answer two of your first questions

```py
>>> from pygraphviz import AGraph
>>> graph = AGraph('test.dot')
>>> edge_count = len(list(graph.iteredges()))
>>> node_count = len(list(graph.iternodes()))
>>> print(node_count, edge_count)
```

To count the trees you will have to come up with some recursive function: use the `.iteredges()` method, which gives you the head and tail nodes which are being connected. Collect this information into some data structure of your choice and get the statistics you need.

Comment: But i have a .gv file. does it provide support for .gv files as well?

Comment: @AhsanFarooqui it doesn't matter what extension the file has. What matters is that the contents of the file are GraphViz graph source code. `.dot` and `.gv` are usually used interchangeably for the files with such source codes. You could also use other extension or no extension at all : )